# Regex positive lookahead not working as I expect

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace certain values of a string. Here's an example string:

`_-[$kr-123] * #,##0.00_-;-[$USD-456] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$GBP-789] * \";-\";??_-;_-@_-`

Specifically, I want to replace `123`, `456`, and `789` with other strings that are retrieved at runtime from a `Dictionary` - in other words I think I need to use a `MatchEvaluator` to replace on the fly, as there are potentially thousands of distinct digit-to-string replacements required.

The closest regex pattern I've gotten to is:

`(?:\[[^\]]*-)(?<Id>[0-9]*)(?:\])`

...where the `Id` group should hold my matches. Currently, this pattern will match e.g. `[$kr-123]`, `[$USD-456]` and `[$GBP-789]` in their entirety. My expectation was that when I switched from non-capturing groups `(?:)` to positive-lookaheads `(?=)` the regex would match only the digit parts in between the brackets. Apparently not. Have I misunderstood positive lookaheads, or is perhaps my regex pattern poor to begin with?

Note that I do indeed get the Group `Id` for each `Match`, but I need the `Id` in itself to be the `Match` because replacing a `Group` in a `Match` doesn't work well inside a `MatchEvaluator` (or so it seems to me - though I'm not totally familiar with the API).

Comment: The first one must be a *lookbehind*, `(?<=\[[^]]*-)[0-9]+(?=])`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew! That both solved my problem and explained _lookbehind_ in one short answer. If you like, you can post and I'll accept as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lookbehind instead of the first non-capturing group because the context you are checking is on the left of the expected match.

```
(?<=\[[^]]*-)[0-9]+(?=])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5D*-%29%28%3F%3CId%3E%5B0-9%5D*%29%28%3F%3D%5D%29&i=_-%5B%24kr-123%5D%20*%20%23%2C%23%230.00_-%3B-%5B%24USD-456%5D%20*%20%23%2C%23%230.00_-%3B_-%5B%24GBP-789%5D%20*%20%5C%22%3B-%5C%22%3B%3F%3F_-%3B_-%40_-). Note you do not need to escape `]` chars as it is the first char in the `[^]]` negated  character class and it is outside a character class in `(?=])`. I'd recommend adding `[` to the lookbehind negated character class though: `(?<=\[[^][]*-)[0-9]+(?=])`, just to play it safe and avoid any overmatching across `[...]` substrings that have no digits inside.

Example code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ {"123", "word1"}, {"456", "word2"} };
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\[[^]]*-)[0-9]+(?=])", m => 
    dict.ContainsKey(m.Value) ? dict[m.Value] : m.Value));
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed the lack of escape character before `]`. That makes sense. Great stuff.